# split array into two equal subarray where index is selected

Tags: java, arrays, sub-array

I need to return an index of the element where the sum of the elements on the left is equal to the sum of the elements on the right. e.g for the array [-3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3], the return value is index 2 since the sum of the elements to the left of the first 3 ([-3, 8]) is the same as the sum of elements to its right ([1, 1, 3]).

So I started by doing a liner-search function to find the intended index,
then after that i attempted to split the array left and right of the selected index but had no success doing so

I haven't had much success getting it to work

```
//linear-search portion,x is the index selected to be split point
public static int findindex(int arr[], int x) {
//if array is null  
if (arr == null) {
        return -1;
    }
//find array length
int len = arr.length;
int i = 0;
//traverse the array
while (i < len) {
//if the i-th element is is x then return the index
    if (arr[i] == x) {
        return i;
    } else {
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
//splint array portion,returns index if not possible
int leftsum = 0;
//treverse array elements
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
//adds current elements to left
    leftsum += arr[i];
//find sum of remader the array elements to rightsum
    int rightsum = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < x; J++)
        rightsum += arr[j];
//split pint index
    if (leftsum == rightsum)
        return i + 1;
}
//if not possible return
return -1;
}

// driver code
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = { -3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3 };
    System.out.println(findindex(array1));
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indent the code so that we can read it.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "but had no success" isnt a valid problem description. And yes: you want others to spend their free time to help you with your problem, so you please take the few minutes it takes to properly format/indet all of your input.

Comment: what is `int x` as a parameter to findindex method?

Comment: int x is ment to be the index point to split the array into two equal parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for solve the problem

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array1 = {-3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3}; // { -3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 19 };
            int indexPosition = GetIndex(array1);
            if (indexPosition != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indexPosition);
            }
        }

        static int GetIndex(int[] param)
        {
            if (param.Length < 0) return -1;
            int leftSum = 0, rightSum = 0; int rightIndex = param.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < rightIndex)
                {
                    if (leftSum > rightSum)
                    {
                        rightSum += param[rightIndex];
                        rightIndex -= 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < rightIndex)
                        {
                            leftSum += param[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    rightSum += param[rightIndex]; // if you are looking for only index position you can comment this line,
                    //variable rightSum and leftSum will give you the sum of left and right side of the array
                    rightIndex -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return rightIndex;
        }
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. One is that the variable i is defined two times in the same method. Another problem is that you only provide one input parameter and not two. I don't even know what parameter x should be and therefore also removed it from my improved version. I also removed the while loop as I don't understand what you tried to do there. Anyways here is my version of the code:

```
public static int findindex(int arr[]) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int len = arr.length;
    int leftsum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        leftsum += arr[i];
        int rightsum = 0;
        for(int j = i+2; j < len; j++)
            rightsum += arr[j];
        if(leftsum == rightsum)
            return i+1;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {-3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3};
    System.out.println(findindex(array1));
}
```

When I removed everything unneccessary from your code the only bug was that you should have initialized j with i+2, because you don't want to include the element at the index itself and only the right side, if I understood the requirements of your code correctly.